# laravel with spatie adding existing permission to a role using API postman

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

i'm trying to add an existing permission to a new role and i'm using API with Spatie and Postman and i always end up with this error image below.

[image]

**Role Post contoller:**

```
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|unique:roles,name',
            'permission' => 'required',
        ]);
        $role = Role::create(['name' => $request->input('name')]);
        $role->syncPermissions($request->input('permission'));

        return response()->json($this-> successStatus);
    }
```

Comment: *There is not permission named `role-list` for guard "api"* I think the error message is pretty clear

Comment: how can i fix this? guard is web

Comment: Have you tried adding `'guard_name' => 'web'` ? https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/multiple-guards/#using-permissions-and-roles-with-multiple-guards

Comment: how to insert can give me example?

Comment: `$role = Role::create(['guard_name' => 'web', 'name' => $request->input('name')]);`

Comment: u mean the issue is not in this line of code? $role->syncPermissions($request->input('permission'));

Comment: Spatie Permission uses separate roles / permissions for each guards. You need to match the guards of both (permissions and roles). When you define a permission with the guard "web", you cannot assign it for the role with the guard "api". There's more info in the documentation link I provided few comments above.

Comment: yeah if i create using table seeder it works but when using API it's not working and the default table model_has_roles is not capturing relationship when API is use, but if using seeder it works.